Customizing of line chart in ggplot2
I am working with R and I trying to make chart in ggplot2. Below you can see my data and my line chart.
# Create data frame
years <- 2000:2005
value <- runif(length(years), min = 100, max = 500) 


    df <- data.frame(Year = years, Value = value)
    
    df$Value<-round(df$Value,1)
    
    ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Value)) +
      geom_line(color = "red", size = 1) +  
      geom_point(color = "red", size = 1) + 
      geom_text(aes(label = Value), vjust = -0.5, size = 4) +
      labs(title = " ",
           x = " ",
           y = " ") +
      theme_minimal() +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(df$Year), max(df$Year), by = 1))+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'black'),
      axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'black')) 


This code generates a line chart, but the resulting line is unfortunately not smooth; instead, it appears rough.

Can anyone help me with how to solve this problem and produce a line chart with a smooth, straight line?

If you save the plot with a high enough resolution/dpi, this shouldn't be a problem; how to change this in the RStudio viewer, I'm not sure

@ila For example which resolution I need to use ? Any proposal ? Also I extracted in png format outside of the R and again same problem.

300 dpi is often recommended for printing, you can usually go lower (say, 150) for computer displays and be fine.

You may also see a jump in quality if you install the ragg package and set your RStudio preferences to Tools > Global Options > General > Graphics set the Backend to AGG.

sjPlot package is a good option to save plots.
plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(color = "red", size = 1) +  
  geom_point(color = "red", size = 1) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Value), vjust = -0.5, size = 4) +
  labs(title = " ",
       x = " ",
       y = " ") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(df$Year), max(df$Year), by = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'black'),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'black')) 


install.packages("sjPlot")
library(sjPlot)
save_plot("plot1.svg", fig = plot1, width = 50, height = 25)

It's what I got:

Note. After saving your plot, you will have SVG file. You can convert this file to PNG with `Inkscape' software (or just google 'SVG to PNG').
